# Weblogic send file through ssl

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic

I have following problem: I need to send a request with attached file to some ip. I use jsp page to send this data. Here some code example:

```
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();                
    connection.setDoInput( true );
        connection.setDoOutput( true );
        URL url = new URL("%myurl");
        connection.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
        connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "text/xml" );
        connection.setRequestProperty( "Accept", "text/xml" );
        connection.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "agent" );
        connection.setConnectTimeout( 100000 );
        connection.setReadTimeout( 100000 );
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();      
        outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write( data );
```

When I use an https connection (%myurl=https://url) I get this error :

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.readBytesPinned(Native Method)
at jrockit.net.SocketNativeIO.socketRead(SocketNativeIO.java:32)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.readFromNetwork(JSSEFilterImpl.java:404)
at weblogic.socket.JSSEFilterImpl.read(JSSEFilterImpl.java:383)
at weblogic.socket.JSSESocket$JSSEInputStream.read(JSSESocket.java:58)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.isHTTP(MessageHeader.java:224)
at weblogic.net.http.MessageHeader.parseHeader(MessageHeader.java:148)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:468)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:377)
at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
at com.abak.portal.sip.MFITestclass.testcall(MFITestclass.java:120)
at jsp_servlet._templates._template0007._avcsfbrfbwcsqvxdrrxfywwrfqubyaqc.__vats_manage._jspService(__vats_manage.java:404)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:416)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:326)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.vignette.portal.website.internal.SingleInvocationFilter.doFilter(SingleInvocationFilter.java:54)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.vignette.portal.website.internal.SingleInvocationFilter.doFilter(SingleInvocationFilter.java:54)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.vignette.portal.website.internal.SingleInvocationFilter.doFilter(SingleInvocationFilter.java:54)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:524)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:444)
at com.epicentric.servlets.ServletUtils.include(ServletUtils.java:189)
at com.epicentric.template.Style.execute(Style.java:384)
at com.epicentric.template.Style.execute(Style.java:206)
at jsp_servlet._templates._template0032._zvbyracvzyuyeurwyvsdazsqfqubyaqc.__jsp_include_page._jspService(__jsp_include_page.java:135)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.vignette.portal.website.internal.SingleInvocationFilter.doFilter(SingleInvocationFilter.java:54)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.vignette.portal.website.internal.SingleInvocationFilter.doFilter(SingleInvocationFilter.java:54)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.vignette.portal.website.internal.SingleInvocationFilter.doFilter(SingleInvocationFilter.java:54)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:524)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:444)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:163)
at com.epicentric.servlets.ServletUtils.include(ServletUtils.java:153)
at com.epicentric.template.Style.execute(Style.java:381)
at com.epicentric.template.Style.execute(Style.java:245)
at com.epicentric.taglib.html.IncludePageContentTag.doStartTag(IncludePageContentTag.java:99)
at jsp_servlet._templates._template0005._zrrrzryxrbvwvbvstvcvtbsrfqubyaqc.__secondary_sip._jsp__tag12(__secondary_sip.java:634)
at jsp_servlet._templates._template0005._zrrrzryxrbvwvbvstvcvtbsrfqubyaqc.__secondary_sip._jspService(__secondary_sip.java:215)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:416)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:326)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.vignette.portal.website.enduser.filters.JSPAccessFilter.doFilterSingleInvocation(JSPAccessFilter.java:46)
at com.vignette.portal.website.internal.SingleInvocationFilter.doFilter(SingleInvocationFilter.java:52)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.vignette.portal.website.internal.SingleInvocationFilter.doFilter(SingleInvocationFilter.java:54)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.vignette.portal.website.internal.SingleInvocationFilter.doFilter(SingleInvocationFilter.java:54)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:524)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:444)
at com.epicentric.servlets.ServletUtils.include(ServletUtils.java:189)
at com.epicentric.template.Style.execute(Style.java:384)
at com.epicentric.template.Style.execute(Style.java:206)
at com.vignette.portal.website.enduser.internal.requestprocessing.system.DefaultRequestProcessor.executeStyle(DefaultRequestProcessor.java:288)
at com.vignette.portal.website.enduser.internal.requestprocessing.system.DefaultRequestProcessor.process(DefaultRequestProcessor.java:194)
at com.vignette.portal.website.enduser.internal.ControllerServlet.service(ControllerServlet.java:200)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.vignette.portal.website.enduser.filters.SiteResolutionFilter.doFilter(SiteResolutionFilter.java:204)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.vignette.portal.website.enduser.filters.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:46)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.vignette.portal.website.enduser.filters.InitPortalContextFilter.doFilter(InitPortalContextFilter.java:52)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.vignette.portal.website.internal.StartupProtectionFilter.doFilterSingleInvocation(StartupProtectionFilter.java:102)
at com.vignette.portal.website.internal.SingleInvocationFilter.doFilter(SingleInvocationFilter.java:52)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.vignette.portal.website.internal.EnvironmentalWrapperFilter.doFilterSingleInvocation(EnvironmentalWrapperFilter.java:56)
at com.vignette.portal.website.internal.SingleInvocationFilter.doFilter(SingleInvocationFilter.java:52)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at com.ttk.abak.portal.servlet.charsetFilter.doFilter(charsetFilter.java:40)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

But:

- if I submit some text data without file - everything is ok
- if I submit without ssl (%myurl=http://url) - everything is ok
- if I try to run this code without Weblogic, through terminal - everything is ok

  How can i fix this?

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: @BrianOchs I added a stacktrace in my question.